# How to echo var In the next code? (stream url)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

First i convert the url (php string) to jquery array,

And now I need the broadcast to work using the var #url.

Works:

```
hls.loadSource('http://149.56.21.86:25461/live/demivadoiscar/Quz2LG/158.ts');
```

Not Works:

```
hls.loadSource('#url');
```

-

```
<?php
$url = "http://149.56.21.86:25461/live/demivadoiscar/Quz2LG/158.ts";
?>

<html>
<body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
<video height="600" id="video" controls></video>

var url = <?php $url?>

<script>
if(Hls.isSupported()){
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource('#url');
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function(){
        video.play();
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
<script>
    var url = "<?php echo $url; ?>";
    if(Hls.isSupported()){
       var video = document.getElementById('video');
       var hls = new Hls();
       hls.loadSource(url);
       hls.attachMedia(video);
       hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function(){
          video.play();
       });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I immediately check

Comment: yeah I know.. I refer to who put the downvote without explain

Comment: Glad to help you! @tavish

Answer (score 3):

You need the url to be a string and use it in your load source function like so:

```
<script>
var url = '<?php echo $url; ?>';
//setup code
hls.loadSource(url);
//the rest of the code
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I immediately check

Comment: You must escape data for the context it appears in. Use json_encode to produce data that is safe in JavaScript. `var url = <?= json_encode($url); ?>;`